# How to identify first occurrence of at least 10 adjacent '1's in a vector in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, vector

How to identify first occurrence of at least 10 adjacent '1's in a vector starting from 1st element which is composed of zeros and ones only?

```
A=[0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1]
```

The code should return index of A (12 in this example), where series of 1's start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Summary: Loops beat `arrayfun` by a mile!**

---

Here's a way to do it using a classic old loop:

```
function x = test_loop(A)
for ii = 1:numel(A)-9
    x = ii*(all(A(ii:ii+9)));
    if x
        break;
    end   
end
end
```

---

**Now, let's investigate the performance of `arrayfun` vs classic `for`-loops:**

The arrayfun approach:

```
test_array = @(A)find(arrayfun(@(x) all(A(x:x+9)==ones(1,10)), 1:numel(A)-9)==1,1)

A = [0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1];
B = repmat(A,1,10);   %% 1x300 array

f = @() test_array(A);
g = @() test_loop(A);
```

Benchmarking results for your array (1x30):

```
timeit(f)
ans =
   2.1397e-04

timeit(g)
ans =
   2.6224e-05
```

Benchmarking results for array of size 1x300:

```
f = @() test_array(B);
g = @() test_loop(B);

timeit(f)
ans =
    0.0021

timeit(g)
ans =
   2.6598e-05
```

If the first sequence of is found late in the vector, the loop will be a bit slower, but still way faster than arrayfun:

```
B(1:220) = 0;

f = @() test_array(B);
g = @() test_loop(B);

timeit(f)
ans =
    0.0021
timeit(g)
ans =
   4.5033e-04
```

**Edit:**

Why increment the counter by 1 for every iteration? The following loop is approximately twice as fast as the for loop, depending on where the sequence appear in the vector, and the spacing between the zeros.

It's still slower that `conv`, but thought it was worth sharing anyway:

```
function x = test_loop(A)    
ii = 1;
x = false;
while ~x
    k = find(A(ii:ii+9)~=1, 1, 'last');
    x = isempty(k)*ii;
    ii = ii + k;
end
end
```

Comment: i agree. the reason under the hood, i guess, is Matlab's anonymous function is slower than plain for-loop(the performance of for-loop is no longer as it was). Indeed, one should pay attention to this when writing performance sensitive code. :+1:

Answer (score 3):

you can use `arrayfun` to do Matlab-style "array comprehension":

```
A=[0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1]
b = arrayfun(@(x) all(A(x:x+9)==ones(1,10)), 1:numel(A)-9)
find(b==1)
```

Comment: @erbal Note that arrayfun is just a disguised for-loop. Also, you should have `find(b==1,1)` for this to be right. =)

Answer (score 3):

You could use a regexp:

```
A = [0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1];
N = 10;
result = regexp(char(A+'0'), ['1{' num2str(N) '}'], 'once');
```

Or convolution:

```
A = [0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1];
N = 10;
result = find(conv(2*A-1, ones(1,N), 'valid')==N, 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Possible solution using diff and find:

```
temp = diff([0 A 0]);
start = find(temp == 1);
finish = find(temp == -1);
result = start(find(finish - start >= 10, 1, 'first'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the kind of "memory-intensive" solution faster? (Can't check here, don't have Matlab any more :´( )

```
A = [0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1];

len_A = length(A);

helper = repmat(A,10,2);

helper = helper(bsxfun(@plus,bsxfun(@plus,(0:10-1)',0:len_A-1)*10,(1:10)'));

result = find(all(helper(:,1:end-10)),1)
```

**EDIT:**
What about:

```
helper = cumsum(A);
result = 1 + find(helper - [helper(11:end) nan(1,10)]==-10,1)
```

should be quite good too